# My app keeps crashing when a TextField is empty

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me, why my app keep getting crashed. Cannot find solution for this and why its happening when TextField is empty

```
 public void contanges(View v){
    TextView wynik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wynik);
    double b = Double.parseDouble(wynik.getText().toString());
    if(wynik.getText().length() == 0 ){
        wynik.setText("Bad opperand!");
    }else if(b % 180 ==0){
        wynik.setText("Bad opperand!");
    }else {
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(wynik.getText().toString());
        BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("0");
        result = new BigDecimal(1 / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(a.doubleValue())));
        wynik.setText(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot convert empty values to double values, use try-catch or use validate your input

Comment: ahhh, yeah, thanks for fast answer :)

Comment: There is no any text if you haven't set any text to TextView via XML

Comment: if your textfield is empty using 'length()' throws an exception, plus you should check your field is not empty before any treatment on it

Answer (score 0):

Don't check for 0 length. Instead use Text`TextUtils.isEmpty()`. This way, you can check if the TextView actually has text to parse before you parse it.

```
TextView wynik = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wynik);
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(wynik.toString().trim())) {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line :

```
Double.parseDouble(wynik.getText().toString());
```

You are trying to parse an empty string to double which is not valid.

Add this line before that

```
if(wynik.getText().length() > 0){
Double.parseDouble(wynik.getText().toString());
}
```

Also it depends what you are passing as a textview value because if it is not been able to parse than also it will `throw an exception`

`Try passing a double value to edittext when not empty`.